# How to use use Pin rather than Arc to pass a Vec<u8> by reference to an async block?

Tags: rust, async-await

I want to do an operation on a `Vec<u8>` multiple times using an `Arc`:

```
use futures::{
    executor::{block_on, ThreadPool},
    task::SpawnExt,
}; // 0.3.4
use std::{pin::*, sync::Arc};

fn foo(b: Arc<Vec<u8>>) {
    println!("{:?}", b);
}

#[test]
fn pin_test() {
    let v = Arc::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
    let mut pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let v1 = v.clone();
        let handle = pool
            .spawn_with_handle(async {
                foo(v1);
            })
            .unwrap();
        block_on(handle);
    }
}
```

I was expecting to be able to `Pin` the `Vec<u8>` instead

```
use futures::{
    executor::{block_on, ThreadPool},
    task::SpawnExt,
}; // 0.3.4
use std::{pin::*, sync::Arc};

fn foo(b: &[u8]) {
    println!("{:?}", b);
}

#[test]
fn pin_test() {
    let v = Pin::new(vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]);
    let mut pool = ThreadPool::new().unwrap();
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let v1 = v.clone();
        let handle = pool
            .spawn_with_handle(async {
                foo(&*v1);
            })
            .unwrap();
        block_on(handle);
    }
}
```

This gives the error:

```
error[E0597]: `v1` does not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:19:23
   |
18 |                .spawn_with_handle(async {
   |   ________________________________-_____-
   |  |________________________________|
   | ||
19 | ||                 foo(&*v1);
   | ||                       ^^ borrowed value does not live long enough
20 | ||             })
   | ||             -
   | ||_____________|
   | |______________value captured here by generator
   |                argument requires that `v1` is borrowed for `'static`
...
23 |        }
   |        - `v1` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I understood that `Pin` should pin the `Vec` data to a specific point, such that all the calls could reference the same data. What is the right way to use `Pin` so that I can pass a reference to `foo()`?

I'm using Rust 1.39.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `move`.

Change

```
let handle = pool
    .spawn_with_handle(async {
        foo(&*v1);
    })
    .unwrap();
```

to

```
let handle = pool
    .spawn_with_handle(async move {
        //                   ^^^^
        foo(&*v1);
    })
    .unwrap();
```

Comment: I'm confused as to what's going on here and if the Pin is even being used. You're doing a clone in either case, and then operating on the cloned value. Moving the cloned value into the async block should work regardless of any Pin. Further, given that your Arc, Pin and Vec all implement clone, it's not clear to me what's even being cloned in each scenario...

Comment: Yeah you are right. Do you have a correct solution?

Comment: This does not pass a `Vec<u8>` by reference to the async block. It *deliberately* transfers ownership of the `Vec` to the block.